# Why are parentheses required around an integer to invoke methods on it?

Tags: python, syntax

This does not work.

```
>>> 10.__str__()
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    10.__str__()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But this works.

```
>>> (10).__str__()
'10'
```

Why are parentheses required around integer in order to invoke its methods? List or other data types don't seem to require it.

```
>>> [1, 2].__str__()
'[1, 2]'
>>> {'a': 'foo'}.__str__()
"{'a': 'foo'}"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html), numeric literals require parentheses because otherwise it is unclear if `.` is denoting a floating point number or a method invocation.

For example, to invoke a method on an integer:

```
(10).__str__()
```

but not

```
10.__str__()
```

Whereas to invoke a method on a floating point number:

```
(10.).__str__()
```

or

```
10..__str__()
```

both work because the first `.` can only be a floating point indicator because it is followed by a `.` invoking the method.

Comment: Very interesting: `10..__str__()`.

Comment: @Chris: Because `10.` gives `10.0`, which is a float object. So `10..__str__() == 10.0.__str__()`.

Comment: @KevinGuan, yes, I intended that as an example, not a request for clarification.

Comment: @Chris Thanks! I have added your example to my answer because it really helps clarify the issue.

Comment: I appreciate the link to the documentation but don't see any discussion of this topic in it.  The closest I could find was "Numeric literals containing a decimal point or an exponent sign yield floating point numbers."